# How to compute fourrier transform on computer?

Tags: julia, fft, fftw

I would like to compute the fourrier transform nummerially.
As a simple example I chose a box function given by

```
function step(x)
if abs(x) < a
    return 1
else 
    return 0
end
end
```

which has the fourier transform

```
function stepff(p)
return 2*sin(a*p)/p
end
```

according to [1]. I would like to use the `fft` algorythm directly for the computation.

---

What I have tried:

I tried using julia for the computation and doing some plots

```
x = -5:dx:5
p = fftfreq(length(x),2pi/dx)
scatter(p, real.(fft(step.(x))))
scatter!(p, imag.(fft(step.(x))))
```

however the real and imaginary parts dont really seem to match the expected result at all.

However the absolute value only seems to be off by a constant

[image: plot absolute value of fft and analytical solution]

Also when looking at the formula, the discrete fourrier transform is given by

```
$$
X_k=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_n \cdot e^{-\frac{i 2 \pi}{N} k n}
$$
```

while the fourrier transform is given by

```
$$
\hat{f}(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-i 2 \pi \xi x} d x
$$
```

I am however unsure how they are related.
I do see some relationship between the two, in particular if I would to approximate the integral by a Riemann sum

```
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx \approx \frac{1}{N}\sum_{N}f(x[N])
$$
```

but other than that I don't know.

I also looked at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/861262/what-is-difference-between-fourier-transform-and-fast-fourier-transform) from maths stackexchange, but it did not really prove to be useful, because the answers dont answer my question.

[1] I took the formula from Lothar Papula but other formula books should give the same result, depending on convention a factor of 2pi may be different or it may be normalized by $1/\sqrt(2\pi)$.

Comment: FFT is for periodic function, while the step functions is not periodic. Usually this results in the energy of higher frequencies spread in the lower frequencies and other problems (see/search *FFT aliasing*)

Comment: The DFT (and thus the FFT) have the origin in the first array element. Your origin is in the middle of the array. This accounts for the difference in phase you observed (magnitude has the same shape, real and imaginary components don’t).